# Create list of randomly selected items based on criteria

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, random, selection

I'm trying to randomly select a list of funds based on their investment strategy.
For instance if I have the following dataframe:

**FundName/Strategy**

- Fund1/Activist
- Fund2/Activist
- Fund3/Activist
- Fund4/Activist
- Fund5/Macro
- Fund6/Macro
- Fund7/Macro

I would like to randomly select 2 funds from each strategy category. I have 18 strategies and thousands of funds.

I tried the following:

```
 Strategylist={'Activist', 'Macro'}

 for x in Strategylist:
     np.random.choice(df[df.loc[:,'Strategy']==x].FundName,2,replace=False)
```

Ideally, the number of fund selected from each strategy would be flexible. For instance if we select:

**Strategy/of funds**

- Activist/2
- Macro/1

Then each time, I run the loop I would get a unique random selection of funds with 2 random activist funds and 1 random macro fund such as Fund1, Fund3, Fund6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup code

```
funds = ["Fund{}".format(i+1) for i in range(7)]
strategies = ['Activist']*4 + ['Macro']*3
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(funds, strat)), columns=('FundName', 'Strategy'))
```

You can get a list of strategies from the data frame

```
all_strategies = set(df['Strategy'])
```

You can then get all of the fund names that match a given strategy like this:

```
my_fund_names = df[df['Strategy']=='Activist']['FundName'].values
```

Like you have in your question, you can then use np.random.choice to select from `my_fund_names`.